# Coredump Analysis

Tags: c++, unix

I have observed a core dump on a UNIX server and have to analyze the cause behind it. 
Following is the output of coredump using mdb

```
Loading modules: [ libc.so.1 libuutil.so.1 ld.so.1 ]
> ::status
debugging core file of pmr_colld_aos (32-bit) from atrcxb2532
file: /opt/ericsson/aos/PDM/bin/pmr_colld_aos
initial argv: /opt/ericsson/aos/PDM/bin/pmr_colld_aos -ORBInitRef NameService=corbaloc::maste
threading model: multi-threaded
status: process terminated by SIGABRT (Abort)

> ::stack
libc.so.1`_lwp_kill+0x15(1, 6)
libc.so.1`raise+0x1f(6)
libc.so.1`abort+0xcd(8026ad0, 8eb2d88, 0, fe2cb9d0, 8ea9f50, 80275b0)
libstdc++.so.6.0.3`_ZN9__gnu_cxx27__verbose_terminate_handlerEv+0xdf(fe2eb0c0, fe2cb9d0, 8026a78, fe2b53cc, fe2b7298, 8ea9f50)
libstdc++.so.6.0.3`_ZN10__cxxabiv111__terminateEPFvvE+0x14(fe2b7298, 8ea9f50, 8026a88, fe2b467a, feffd888, fe2cb9d0)
libstdc++.so.6.0.3`_ZN10__cxxabiv112__unexpectedEPFvvE(1, fe2cb9d0, 8026af8, fe2b52d6, fe2b53ac, fe217a44)
libstdc++.so.6.0.3`_ZN10__cxxabiv112__unexpectedEPFvvE+0x14(fe2b53ac, fe217a44, feffa320, 0, 8026ad8, fe2b7298)
libstdc++.so.6.0.3`__cxa_call_unexpected+0x42(8ea9f80, 8026b40, 8c70120, 82aa448, 8e382a8, 8026b20)
_ZN21PDRFileTimeoutHandler5checkEv+0xa10(fe17f000, fdfa2a00, 8026c90, fe0a5bf6, fe180680, 0)
main+0x1309(2, 8026e10, 8026e24)
_start+0x80(4, 8027618, 8027682, 802764c, 8027640, 0)
> $C
080269c4 libc.so.1`_lwp_kill+0x15(1, 6)
080269dc libc.so.1`raise+0x1f(6)
08026a28 libc.so.1`abort+0xcd(8026ad0, 8eb2d88, 0, fe2cb9d0, 8ea9f50, 80275b0)
08026a48 libstdc++.so.6.0.3`_ZN9__gnu_cxx27__verbose_terminate_handlerEv+0xdf(fe2eb0c0, fe2cb9d0, 8026a78, fe2b53cc, fe2b7298, 8ea9f50)
08026a58 libstdc++.so.6.0.3`_ZN10__cxxabiv111__terminateEPFvvE+0x14(fe2b7298, 8ea9f50, 8026a88, fe2b467a, feffd888, fe2cb9d0)
08026a78 libstdc++.so.6.0.3`_ZN10__cxxabiv112__unexpectedEPFvvE(1, fe2cb9d0, 8026af8, fe2b52d6, fe2b53ac, fe217a44)
08026a88 libstdc++.so.6.0.3`_ZN10__cxxabiv112__unexpectedEPFvvE+0x14(fe2b53ac, fe217a44, feffa320, 0, 8026ad8, fe2b7298)
08026af8 libstdc++.so.6.0.3`__cxa_call_unexpected+0x42(8ea9f80, 8026b40, 8c70120, 82aa448, 8e382a8, 8026b20)
08026c68 _ZN21PDRFileTimeoutHandler5checkEv+0xa10(fe17f000, fdfa2a00, 8026c90, fe0a5bf6, fe180680, 0)
08026dec main+0x1309(2, 8026e10, 8026e24)
08026e04 _start+0x80(4, 8027618, 8027682, 802764c, 8027640, 0)
> $G
C++ symbol demangling enabled
> ::quit
```

Can anyone help me in understanding this output?

Please note that the code has been written in the pmr_colld_aos in directory - /opt/ericsson/aos/PDM/bin/pmr_colld_aos.
Also, I just want to know how to understand such outputs which will help me in backtracing the code.

Comment: Welcome to SO. However, this question is low-quality. Backtracing the code without code?

Comment: Can you please help me in understanding the output?

Comment: @ArchnaSharma what is the software that is crashing (What is `/opt/ericsson/aos/PDM/bin/pmr_colld_aos`)? If this isn't software that you yourself have written then you should ask in [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/) instead. Have you looked at the log files for that software?

Comment: Here's the stack part of the log, stripped down to a minimum an demangled with [c++filtjs](http://pear.warosu.org/c++filtjs/): http://pastebin.com/bvYL7GC3 . It shows that `unexpected` was called while in `PDRFileTimeoutHandler::check()` (resulting in `terminate` then `abort`). http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/unexpected : "std::unexpected() is called by the C++ runtime _when a dynamic exception specification is violated_: an exception is thrown from a function whose exception specification forbids exceptions of this type. std::unexpected() may also be called directly from the program."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you got there is the backtrace of the crash. The last routine that's part of the program was FileTimeoutHandler5checkEv() so it's likely that the error is in there. Everything after this point is part of the C++ library.

But if you really want to examine it, then you should load the core file into GDB along with the program that caused it. It's way easier than examining the core file with mdb.

Comment: @Nikos-Does pstack and pflag output also helps in debugging the coredump ?